# How should I insulate a 3 story 1920's lath stucco house in New England?

Tags: insulation, stucco

Best and worst ways to insulate 3 story 1920's lath stucco house in New England?
Is there any type of insulation I should be careful to avoid? In particular, I am concerned about the permeability of the stucco, and the use of cellulose in such an old house. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you insulating from the inside or from the outside?  Are we talking balloon framing here?

Comment: From the inside. As for balloon framing, I am not sure. I  have been hoping it would be possible to  blow in insulation under the horsehair plaster. But given that, I can see it maybe important to know. Do you know how I could tell or find out?

Comment: What type of wiring is in this house if knob and tube blow in insulation can create a hazard. If the wiring has been upgraded to romex blow in would be fine.

Comment: I have upgraded electrical, replaced all knob and tube. My concern is that the stucco seems likely to not be waterproof.